# Style RadSlider Ticks

Tags: wpf, telerik

Tererik's documentation is deplorable (or I can't find it). Anyway, anyone have a tip on styling the tick marks for a `RadSlider`?

I've managed to find this much, that I need to create a `RadBarStyle` but setting the `Foreground` doesn't change the ticks, setting the `Background` does change the bar's background, but has no effect on the ticks.

My code:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ticks" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadTickBar}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="Brightness" Margin="5 5 0 10" />
    <telerik:RadSlider ValueChanged="RadSlider_ValueChanged"
                        Ticks="0"
                        TickPlacement="Both" 
                        Minimum="-100" Maximum="200" LargeChange="10" 
                        SmallChange="5"
                        TickBarStyle="{StaticResource ticks}"
                        />

</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tick is a rectangle, if you just want to change it's color you can use something like this:

```
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="ticks" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadTickBar}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <TextBlock Margin="5 5 0 10" Text="Brightness" />
        <telerik:RadSlider LargeChange="10"
                           Maximum="200"
                           Minimum="-100"
                           SmallChange="5"
                           TickBarStyle="{StaticResource ticks}"
                           TickPlacement="Both"
                           Ticks="0"
                           ValueChanged="RadSlider_ValueChanged">
            <telerik:RadSlider.TickTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Width="1"
                               Height="5"
                               Fill="Red" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:RadSlider.TickTemplate>
        </telerik:RadSlider>
    </StackPanel>
```